# How to change horizontal size of Angular Material datepicker?

Tags: angular-material

This is the datepicker that I want to set my custom horizontal size:
https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.5/demo/datepicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean but to set the horizontal size of the input of the date picker you can override css class as follow

```
.md-datepicker-input-container {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me in Angular Material 6

```
.mat-datepicker-content .mat-calendar
{ 
     zoom: 0.85;
}
```

Comment: this resizes the calendar for me. I had to include `::ng-deep ` before `.mat-datepicker-content` to make it work for me

Comment: it just saved a lot of time for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by setting the display to block on the `mat-form-field`. I have other form controls which I'm trying to have matching width's so this solution worked for me. Might work for someone else.

In HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="display-block">
    <...date picker and other form elements...>
</mat-form-field>
```

In css:

```
.mat-form-field.display-block {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: only answer that works in ng11 and very simple thx

Answer (score 1):

Update below CSS class for the page or globally, this will help to reduce the icon `line-height` and `height` so we can reduce the height of the datetime picker.

```css
.mat-icon-button {
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 16px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    line-height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Angular Material 15, I needed **!important** in order it to work

```
::ng-deep {
  .mat-datepicker-content .mat-calendar  {
    width: YOUR_WIDTH !important;
    height: YOUR_HEIGHT !important;
  }
}
```